# Getting files from multiple folders with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, path, dataset

I need to build an array with some files from a dataset with a structure like this:

1. FolderA:

   - FolderA1:
   - FolderA2:

     - File01.txt
2. FolderB:

   - FolderB1:
   - FolderB2:

     - File01.txt

Let's say I need the File01.txt from Folders A,B,D and F. How can I get those files?

Comment: Have you tried using `glob` ?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but take a look at `os.walk` : "Generate the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top itself), it yields a 3-tuple `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)`."

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#module-glob) module:

```
import glob

base_dir = '.'
folders = ('A', 'B', 'D', 'F')
pattern = '{}/[{}]/*/File01.txt'.format(base_dir, ''.join(folders))
for filename in glob.glob(pattern):
    print(filename)
```

The creates the glob pattern `./[ABDF]/*/File01.txt`. If the script is executed in the directory containing the top level folders in your example, it will output:

```
./A/A2/File01.txt
./B/B2/File01.txt
```

You can also use relative and absolute paths; just change `base_dir` as appropriate. Then you can execute the script from anywhere.

Comment: Here folder names are hardcoded